# Change navigation keys in Windows clipboard history popup

Tags: autohotkey

You can normally navigate elements of Windows clipboard history popup (activated by Win key + v) using arrow keys. I want to remap them so Up key is Ctrl+i and Down key is Ctrl+k. Unfortunately popup disappears immediately when Ctrl button is down. I was able to prevent popup close using Autohotkey `lCtrl::return` but this also breaks other mappings like `^k:: Send, {down}`. Any idea how to do it using Autohotkey?

Comment: It only happens on Windows 10, not on Windows 11.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 so it is problably the same issue. But I don't want to upgrade to Windows 11 (yet).

Comment: `Ctrl` is a bit tricky. Can you send just `k` and `i`, or maybe `+k`, `+i`